# having trouble extending pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying the "Extend pandas" functionality but can't seem to get it to work. I'm trying to follow the example provided by pandas.

[Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html)

Heres my code so far with fake data

```
import pandas as pd
data =pd.DataFrame({'ID1':[1,2], 'ID2':[3,4], 'value':[5,6]})
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("ext")
class my_extension:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self.dataset = pandas_obj
    @property
    def retrieve_ID(self, ID):
        return self[self['ID1']==ID]

    def method2(self, ID):
        return self[self['ID2']==ID]
```

Basically, the end result that I want is for me to type "data.ext." and hit tab and see retrieve_ID and method2 as an option for my functions

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you are missing the `self.dataset` part (and don't think you need the `@property` there). Btw this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
data =pd.DataFrame({'ID1':[1,2], 'ID2':[3,4], 'value':[5,6]})
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("ext")
class my_extension:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self.dataset = pandas_obj
    #@property
    def retrieve_ID(self, ID):
        return self.dataset[self.dataset['ID1']==ID]

    def method2(self, ID):
        return self.dataset[self.dataset['ID2']==ID]
```

Comment: this works!  thank you.  What does @property do?  and why did we need to add self.dataset in the returns?

Comment: We need `self.dataset` because that actually refers to your `pandas_obj` (and `self` refers to your `my_extension` class). For more on `property`, this is a good link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work